# Good Java project architecture with database

Tags: java, architecture, struts, database-connection

I facing problem of database connection in my project in which i used struts. I cant understand that how i manage my database connections. I want my site good in based on accessing becoz it will get million after launch.

And also face heap size problem in that .

I cant understand that how i will manage my architechture.
Plz guide me,if some one have the knowledge .
I want good java architecture  with good management of database connection.

Comment: No offence but if you are making a site where you expect to have millions of users after launch, you need a much more dedicated look at all aspects of your architecture and preferably by someone with experience in building such applications. Managing DB Connections is, if i may say so, only ONE of the things that you need to look at. Performance, Scalability in general, Caching, Security are just some aspects that need to be looked at and sorted out in your architectural choices.

Comment: A **must read**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site

Comment: @In Sane: hope I could vote your comment more than once.

Comment: @user416120: It seems if that you simply don't understand how to manage you connections (oposed to "can't understand why this particular thing happens") you DON'T have an architecture. Try to learn (among other things) how connections are managed in an application (connection pools, transaction delimiting, care in ordering updating actions, etc, etc, etc).

Comment: for more info please visit http://www.rameshsengani.in

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) for DB operation.
It is very good ORM tool

There should be 3 modules atleast  for your case of architecture.

1)WebApp
2)Service module
3)Database [Hibernate Module]

Answer (score 0):

Spring has some very good facilities to help you manage DB connections. Have a look at part IV of the documentation : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-data-tier.html

Spring can help you wether you want to do plain JDBC / SQL or if you want to use a more fancy ORM like Hibernate.

If you want to sustain really high load, that's of course just the begining. You will need a lot of profiling, measuring, tweaking ...

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the [layered architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture) approach. Struts itself is based upon the MVC architectural pattern.

From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller), ...In MVC:

> Models are not data access objects; however, in very simple apps that have little domain logic there is no real distinction to be made.
>
> Many applications use a persistent storage mechanism such as a database to store data. MVC does not specifically mention the data access layer because it is understood to be underneath or encapsulated by the model.

So, you can comeup with you own data access layer that would work *underneath* your Model; Checkout [A Simple Data Access Layer using Hibernate](http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbNov2003.html)